# python. После копирования файла указать питону кодировку содержимого

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.8

```
nf2 = input("Название игры: ")
with open ('index.html', 'r') as f:
  old_data = f.read()

new_data = old_data.replace('namegame', nf2)

with open ('index.html', 'w') as f:
  f.write(new_data)
```

Скопировал файл и вставил в другую папку с помощью shutil. Когда в файле была только одна-две строки, то я спокойно мог заменить "namegame" на 'nf2'. Но когда в файле уже стало 200 и более строк, то начало кричать на кодировку чтоль. Короче вот то что выводит:

```
File "D:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: ' charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1386: character maps to (undefinded)
```

Comment: Откройте файл любым текстовым редактором и посмотрите что за странный символ стоит в позиции 1386

Comment: @andreymal Ничего особенного. Просто слово "игры" и между буквой "г" и "р"

Comment: @andromeda а где сама строчка 23 в коде? Попробуй указать параметр кодировки , например, здесь следующим образом: with open ('index.html', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f: . Но только я не уверен, правильно ли написал название кодировки и ту ли кодировку пишу.

Comment: Да, кодировка файла utf-8 изначально, но при копировании файла, пайтон чтоль не понимает и ему нужно указать. Я пробовал ввести encoding="utf8" но вводил в начале (перед index.html). Мб не в начале нужно было, а в конце хд)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо огромное) Я дурак ставил encoding перед index.html. Поставил как ты написал и всё ок)

Comment: @andromeda только я не "andreymal" :D А так да, если у тебя есть неименованные параметры, то они всегда должны быть перед именованными, т.е. не может быть такого, что сначала идут именнованные, а потом в середине неименованные :)

Comment: только я не "andreymal" - oopsy